# Are files run on local machines cached?

Tags: html, caching

I had a nightmare last night. I've been working on an mvc website. I'd created my master view and had ALL my styling in a seperate css file. I've created a ton of View pages as well. All of a sudden, out of nowhere, I get the blue screen of death. Checkdisk runs etc and when the OS gets back up and running my masterpage and css file are corrupted beyond belief. I have to start all over again.

I'm at work now and and had an aha moment. I can't check right now but I wondered if the old css file would still be in my cache/temp internet files folder? I checked at work for another project but non of the files that are run locally (on localhost) seem to be in there (which kind of makes sense but I'm praying it's not normally the case).

Does anyone know if local files are normally cached? Also, if a cached file is changed and localhost is re-run, the old file will be overwritten won't it?

Trying to hold onto a glimer of hope before going home to disect my file system. Three days of work down the pan! 1 lesson on backing up learnt!

Comment: another one learns to backup and version control the hard way.  I've been there.

Comment: "Does anyone know if local files are normally cached?" 

AFAIK, yes.

"Also, if a cached file is changed and localhost is re-run, the old file will be overwritten won't it?"

It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CSS files normally get cached.

Comment: managed to check last night and found the css file in the cache, thank god!